# LLVM Instruction Scheduling

Tags: llvm, scheduling, compiler-optimization, instructions

As is noted in [Getting Started with LLVM Core Libraries](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781782166924/) there are three distinct instruction schedulers in the LLVM backend. One of them runs before register allocation and it can be selected using the `-pre-RA-sched` option. The other two run after register allocation. How can I choose or disable each of these three schedulers? Do they have any interferences which each other?

Answer (score 4):

See `llc --help-hidden` for more details. Here are three options corresponding to the pre-RA SDNode, pre-RA MI and post-RA MI scheduling.

```
 -pre-RA-sched        - Instruction schedulers available (before register allocation):
 -enable-misched      - Enable the machine instruction scheduling pass.
 -enable-post-misched - Enable the post-ra machine instruction scheduling pass.
```

You can select exactly which scheduler to be used in pre-RA SDNode scheduling, but not for the others.